# First character of the reading from the text file : ï»¿

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, filereader

If I write this code, I get this as output --> This first: ï»¿
 and then the other lines

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "myFile.txt"));

    String line;
    while (line = br.readLine() != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: I guess it's because of encoding.

Comment: Maybe the BOM? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: It is the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: I solved so:       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     new FileInputStream("dictionary.txt"),"UTF8")); 
    if (line.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
     line = line.substring(1);
    }

Comment: That will strip \uFEFF from the beginning of every line, though. I think you only want to strip the one at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Yes, I do it only for the first line read.

Comment: @Milton90 : this is a good solution.that has helped me .thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You are getting the characters ï»¿ on the first line because this sequence is the [UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). If a text file begins with a BOM, it's likely it was generated by a Windows program like Notepad.

To solve your problem, we choose to read the file explicitly as UTF-8, instead of whatever default system character encoding (US-ASCII, etc.):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"),
        "UTF-8"));
```

Then in UTF-8, the byte sequence ï»¿ decodes to one character, which is U+FEFF. This character is optional - a legal UTF-8 file may or may not begin with it. So we will skip the first character only if it's U+FEFF:

```
in.mark(1);
if (in.read() != 0xFEFF)
  in.reset();
```

And now you can continue with the rest of your code.

Comment: If I am correct, BOM character would occur only once in the entire file?

Comment: It can occur multiple times if a dumb program concatenated multiple files that each contained a header BOM.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be in encoding used.
try this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream("yourfile"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I'd say it *definitely* is the encoding ;)

Comment: I've already tried. In place of ï»¿ becomes '?'

Comment: It could be because of IDE you're using. Sometimes they set the default encoding of native operating system