# Weird buffer initial character

Tags: java, buffer

I'm trying to read an object called Word that has a char array as attribute. I'm trying to read words from a text file (.txt), but i have a problem only with the first word. When i use my method it reads a character thats not in the word (i think its a new line or something)

Here's my method

```
public void read(BufferedReader f) {
    numCaracteres=0;

        while ((caracter != ' ')) {
            caracteres[numCaracteres]=caracter;
            numCaracteres++;
            caracter=(char) f.read();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

PS: After i write a word in the file, i separate it with the next using a blank space

Comment: did you checked the encoding of your file? maybe BOM problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: "*When i use my method it reads a character thats not in the word*" how is that possible? This method will not even compile because of (1) wrong `{` `}` placement, (2) lack of `try` before `catch` block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405165/first-character-of-the-reading-from-the-text-file-ï

Comment: You are `read`ing *after* you store the character into the array. That must fail for the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: What is the default `caracter`? Also I assume that should have been `character`.

Comment: Why don't you use java.util.Scanner? This will do all the white space skipping for you.

Comment: A char array is an unwieldy way for storing character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Throw away read and use:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner( someBufferedReader );
while( scn.hasNext() ){
    String word = scn.next();
    // process word
}
```