# java reading a file through scanner and its appending character ? for first line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

File1 Content:

```
AddressBlock1|AddressBlock2

Main Rd. 1|Westpunt
```

EOL is Windows and encoding is UTF8

Java code snippet to read:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(File1),"UTF-8");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Output:

```
?AddressBlock1|AddressBlock2
Main Rd. 1|Westpunt
```

Its appending ? in first line. What could be the reason?

Comment: Probably [BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405165/first-character-of-the-reading-from-the-text-file-%C3%AF)

Comment: You need to make sure that when you read the file, you also use UTF-8 encoding. If not, you'll have this "strange" output yes.