# Bug returnin a double value from a function in java

Tags: java, function, methods

my function is returning 0 only in the first position of my vector, after this the function works correctly, I've debugged the program and it seems that the `.equal()` string method is not working in the first time of the loop, below the entire code with the simulation:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication14;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author Iago Sestrem Ochôa
 */
public class JavaApplication14 {

    public static double retornaSimRC (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}  

public static double retornaSimDC (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
} 

public static double retornaSimDTS (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimMOB (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Limitado") && a2.equals("Limitado"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Normal") && a2.equals("Normal")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Limitado") && a2.equals("Normal")) || (a2.equals("Limitado") && a1.equals("Normal"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimART (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimRM (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimBUR (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimTOF (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}  

public static double retornaSimSIN (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}  

public static double retornaSimATG (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimNR (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimDJ (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimTCSE (String a1, String a2) {


        if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Leve")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Moderado")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Importante")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Leve")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Leve"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.5;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.2;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Leve") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Leve") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.4;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Importante") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.65;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}   

public static double retornaSimHLAB27 (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Negativo") && a2.equals("Negativo")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Positivo") && a2.equals("Positivo")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Negativo") && a2.equals("Positivo")) || (a2.equals("Negativo") && a1.equals("Positivo"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Negativo") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Negativo") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.3;    
        } else if ((a1.equals("Positivo") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Positivo") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.3;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimIL (String a1, String a2) {
        if (a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Ausente")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Moderado")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Leve")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Importante")){
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Muito Importante") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")){
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Leve")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Leve"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.3;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Leve")) || (a2.equals("Moderado") && a1.equals("Leve"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Moderado") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Moderado") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.2;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Leve") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Leve") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Leve") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.2;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Importante") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double  retornaSimER(String a1, String a2){
         if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Ausente")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Moderado")) {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Importante")){
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Muito Importante") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")){
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Ausente")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Ausente"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Não") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Moderado")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Moderado"))) {
                return 0.7;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.5;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Ausente") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Ausente") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.2;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Importante")) || (a2.equals("Moderado") && a1.equals("Importante"))) {
                return 0.6;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Moderado") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Leve") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.3;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Importante") && a2.equals("Muito Importante")) || (a2.equals("Importante") && a1.equals("Muito Importante"))) {
                return 0.8;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

public static double retornaSimDL(String a1, String a2){
        if (a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Sim"))  {
                return 1;
        } else if (a1.equals("Não") && a2.equals("Não")) {
                return 1;
        } else if ((a1.equals("Sim") && a2.equals("Não")) || (a2.equals("Sim") && a1.equals("Não"))) {
                return 0.1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Double pesodts;
        Double pesoil;
        Double pesoer;
        Double pesotcse;
        Double pesoart;
        Double pesorm;
        Double pesobur;
        Double pesotof;
        Double pesosin;
        Double pesoatg;
        Double pesonr;
        Double pesohlab27;
        Double pesodj;
        Double pesodl;
        Double pesorc;
        Double pesodc;
        Double pesomob;
        String dtssel;
        String ilsel;
        String ersel;
        String tcsesel;
        String artsel;
        String rmsel;
        String bursel;
        String tofsel;
        String sinsel;
        String atgsel;
        String nrsel;
        String hlab27sel;
        String djsel;
        String dlsel;
        String rcsel;
        String dcsel;
        String mobsel;
        //VECTORS TO STORE THE DATA FROM TXT FILE
        String[] iltxt = new String[49];
        String[] ertxt = new String[49];
        String[] tcsetxt = new String[49];
        String[] arttxt = new String[49];
        String[] rmtxt  = new String[49];
        String[] burtxt  = new String[49];
        String[] toftxt = new String[49];
        String[] atgtxt = new String[49];
        String[] nrtxt = new String[49];
        String[] hlab27txt = new String[49];
        String[] djtxt = new String[49];
        String[] dltxt = new String[49];
        String[] rctxt = new String[49];
        String[] dctxt = new String[49];
        String[] mobtxt = new String[49];
        String[] dtstxt = new String[49];
        String[] sintxt = new String[49];
        String[] diagnosticotxt = new String[49];
        // CREATES THE VALUE FOR THE SIMULATION
        dtssel = "Sim"; 
        ilsel =  "Ausente";
        ersel = "Moderado";
        tcsesel = "Moderado";
        artsel = "Não";
        rmsel = "Não";
        bursel = "Não";
        tofsel = "Não";
        sinsel = "Não";
        atgsel = "Não";
        nrsel = "Não";
        hlab27sel = "Negativo";
        djsel = "Não";
        dlsel = "Sim";
        rcsel = "Sim";
        dcsel = "Sim";
        mobsel = "Limitado";     
        pesodts = 1.0;
        pesoil = 1.0;
        pesoer = 1.0;
        pesotcse = 1.0;
        pesoart = 1.0;
        pesorm = 1.0;
        pesobur = 1.0;
        pesotof = 1.0;
        pesosin = 1.0;
        pesoatg = 1.0;
        pesonr = 1.0;
        pesohlab27 = 1.0;
        pesodj = 1.0;
        pesodl = 1.0;
        pesorc = 1.0;
        pesodc = 1.0;
        pesomob = 1.0;
        //AUX STRING
        String[] aux = new String[17];
        //READ FILE
      int cont = 1;  
      try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("File.txt");
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
            String linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
            aux = linha.split(",");
            dltxt[0] = aux[0];
            rctxt[0] = aux[1];
            dctxt[0] = aux[2];
            mobtxt[0] = aux[3];
            dtstxt[0] = aux[4];
            iltxt[0] = aux[5];
            ertxt[0] = aux[6];
            tcsetxt[0] = aux[7];
            arttxt[0] = aux[8];
            rmtxt[0] = aux[9];
            burtxt[0] = aux[10];
            toftxt[0] = aux[11];
            sintxt[0] = aux[12];
            atgtxt[0] = aux[13];
            nrtxt[0] = aux[14];
            hlab27txt[0] = aux[15];
            djtxt[0] = aux[16];
            diagnosticotxt[0] = aux[17];
             linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
            while (linha != null) {
                    aux = linha.split(",");
                    dltxt[cont] = aux[0];
                    rctxt[cont] = aux[1];
                    dctxt[cont] = aux[2];
                    mobtxt[cont] = aux[3];
                    dtstxt[cont] = aux[4];
                    iltxt[cont] = aux[5];
                    ertxt[cont] = aux[6];
                    tcsetxt[cont] = aux[7];
                    arttxt[cont] = aux[8];
                    rmtxt[cont] = aux[9];
                    burtxt[cont] = aux[10];
                    toftxt[cont] = aux[11];
                    sintxt[cont] = aux[12];
                    atgtxt[cont] = aux[13];
                    nrtxt[cont] = aux[14];
                    hlab27txt[cont] = aux[15];
                    djtxt[cont] = aux[16];
                    diagnosticotxt[cont] = aux[17];
                    aux = null;
                    cont++;
                    linha = lerArq.readLine(); 
            }
            arq.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Error: %s.\n",
            e.getMessage());
      }
      // CALCULATE RBC
      Double[] prob = new Double[49];
      for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {     
           prob[i] = (((pesodts * retornaSimDTS(dtssel,dtstxt[i])) + (pesonr * retornaSimNR(nrsel,nrtxt[i])) + (pesoil *(retornaSimIL(ilsel,iltxt[i]))) + (pesoer * (retornaSimER(ersel,ertxt[i]))) + (pesotcse * (retornaSimTCSE(tcsesel,tcsetxt[i]))) + (pesoart * (retornaSimART(artsel,arttxt[i]))) + (pesorm * (retornaSimRM(rmsel,rmtxt[i]))) +  (pesobur * (retornaSimBUR(bursel,burtxt[i]))) + (pesotof * (retornaSimTOF(tofsel,toftxt[i]))) + (pesosin * (retornaSimSIN(sinsel,sintxt[i]))) + (pesoatg * (retornaSimATG(atgsel,atgtxt[i]))) + (pesohlab27 * (retornaSimHLAB27(hlab27sel,hlab27txt[i]))) + (pesodj * (retornaSimDJ(djsel,djtxt[i]))) + (pesodl * (retornaSimDL(dlsel,dltxt[i]))) + (pesorc * (retornaSimRC(rcsel,rctxt[i]))) + (pesodc * (retornaSimDC(dcsel,dctxt[i]))) + (pesomob * (retornaSimMOB(mobsel,mobtxt[i]))))/(pesodts+pesoil+pesoer+pesotcse+pesoart+pesorm+pesobur+pesotof+pesosin+pesoatg+pesohlab27+pesodj+pesodl+pesorc+pesodc+pesomob+pesonr)*100);
           System.out.println("Coount -> " + i);
           System.out.println("SEL");
           System.out.println(dlsel);
           System.out.println("TXT");
           System.out.println(dltxt[i]);
           System.out.println(retornaSimDL(dlsel,dltxt[i]));
           System.out.println(prob[i]);
      }


}

}
```

The problem is occurring in the `retornaSimDL()`, if you execute the code above you will see on count 0 in the console that my two inputs are `Sim` and the function returns 0, on count 6 you will see the same values of the count 0 (two inputs `Sim`) and the function returns 1, the console output below for this two values:

```
Coount -> 0
SEL
Sim
TXT
﻿Sim
0.0
94.11764705882352

Coount -> 6
SEL
Sim
TXT
Sim
1.0
77.94117647058823
```

Someone knows what is happening?

The txt file:

```
Sim,Sim,Sim,Limitado,Sim,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Importante,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Muito Importante,Importante,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Muito Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática
Sim,Não,Sim,Normal,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante 
Sim,Sim,Sim,Limitado,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Ausente,Leve,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Muito Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Ausente,Moderado,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Sim,Ausente,Moderado,Leve,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Sim,Não,Sim,Normal,Não,Ausente,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Ausente,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Moderado,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Importante,Moderado,Sim,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Sim,Ausente,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Ausente,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Ausente,Ausente,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Negativo,Não,Artrite Reumática
Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Sim,Leve,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Negativo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica 
Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Não,Importante,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Sim,Sim,Não,Limitado,Sim,Importante,Muito Importante,Importante,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Muito Importante,Ausente,Moderado,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Artrite Reumática
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Sim,Sim,Sim,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Muito Importante,Moderado,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Sim,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Moderado,Moderado,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Sim,Sim,Não,Normal,Não,Ausente,Ausente,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Sim,Sim,Normal,Não,Ausente,Importante,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Sim,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Não,Não,Positivo,Não,Espondilite Anquilosante
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Leve,Moderado,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Limitado,Não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Importante,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
Sim,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Leve,Importante,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite de Gota
Não,Não,Não,Normal,Não,Moderado,Importante,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Sim,Não,Não,Não,Artrite Reumatica
```

Answer (score 2):

Try printing the values using

```
System.out.println( '[' dlsel + ']');
```

and

```
System.out.println( '[' dltxt[i] + ']');
```

to see if there are any extra spaces. Also print dlsel.length() and dltxt[i].length() to ensure they are both 3.

Comment: The `dltxt[i].length()` is 4 and the `dlsel.length()` is 3, do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: I am using an UTF-8 encoding in the TXT file.

Comment: It's probably the Byte Order Mark that some things unnecessarily put at the beginning of a UTF-8 file, especially on (or from) Windows; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405840/2868801 (and its dupe, but this is better focussed).