# OPENCSV populating first column as null

Tags: opencsv

I am trying to read a csv file using opencsv using HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy. Opencsv populates my first column of csv as null everytime. 
Here is my code :

Entity Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "status", required = true)
    @Column(name = "status", length = 5, nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "type", required = true)
    @Column(name = "type", length = 5, nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "percentage", required = true)
    @Column(name = "percentage", nullable = false)
    private Integer percentage;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    @CsvBindByName(column = "date", required = true)
    @CsvDate(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
}
```

Reading logic:

```
 final HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MyEntity> mpngInfo= new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
                mappingInfo.setType(MyEntity.class);
 final CsvToBean<MyEntity> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();
File file = new File(<path>);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file),';');
 final List<MyEntity> list = csvToBean.parse(mpngInfo, reader, true);
//here in list the first column is always populated as null.
```

My CSV :

type;status;percentage;date
ACTIVE;USD;25;2014-01-01
ACTIVE;GBP;25;2014-01-01

Note: Even if I switch 'type' with 'percentage' then it starts populating percentage as null because 'percentage' column becomes the first column.

I figured out the problem that is with the first character of file.
In my case it's "ï»¿"type;status;percentage;date

The problem is listed here :
[First character of the reading from the text file : ï»¿](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405165/first-character-of-the-reading-from-the-text-file-%C3%AF)

How can I solve this in opencsv? Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 30):

I met the same problem.

### Solution

I saved the csv file again by utf-8 **without BOM**.
Then the first column is set with correct value.
No code needs to be changed.
I use the text editor named sakura.After choosing encoding as utf-8,a checkbox of BOM is enabled.Uncheck it and save the csv file.I think other editors have the same BOM option.

### Reason

> A BOM-ed UTF-8 string will start with the three following bytes. EF BB
>   BF

The three bytes added to your csv file may changed your first column name.

Comment: Rather than link to existing questions you should raise a flag to mark this question as a duplicate of the one you believe answers it.

Comment: Yes, it was the format issue for me also.

Comment: If using `Sublime Text`, choose `File > Save With Encoding > UTF-8`

Comment: VSCode: bottom right (on taskbar) click on encoding, save with encoding, UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

In intellij you can simply click on the file and on the top menu File -> File Properties -> Remove BOM. Which will do the magic for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for removing BOM from csv file.

```
String localFilePath = "some_path_inputfile";
String localFilePath_Out = "some_path_outputfile";

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(localFilePath));
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(localFilePath_Out)) {

        // Read the file and skip the BOM characters
        int firstChar = reader.read();
        if (firstChar != 0xFEFF) {
            // If the first character is not the BOM, write it to the output
            writer.write(firstChar);
        }

        int nextChar;
        while ((nextChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
            // Write the remaining characters to the output
            writer.write(nextChar);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After this you can use the output file as it does not having BOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to write files and swap in memory you can use streams as well , for me i simply recreated the stream without BOM

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream removeBOM(InputStream is) {
    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        int firstChar = reader.read();
        if (firstChar != 0xFEFF) {
            writer.write(firstChar);
        }

        int nextChar;
        while ((nextChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
            writer.write(nextChar);
        }

        writer.close();
        return os;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BusinessException(ErrorBean.withError(Errors.FILE_TYPE, "Error parsing csv", ""));
    }
}
```

And use as

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = removeBOM(file.getInputStream());
Inputstream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```